# jQuery remove() moves view to top of screen on execution

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items with a trash button on each. This calls a `.remove()` event handler in jQuery. This all works fine, but on the removal of the `<li>` element the page returns to the top, I would like the element to be removed without the page scroll changing position. Is there a way to prevent this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

A

Comment: You mean that the browser scrolls to the top, or that it 'jumps' to the top? This is probably a CSS problem.

Comment: Add a `return: false` on the anchor click event

Comment: Show us the HTML and the jQuery code. I suspect your "trash button" is actually an `<a>` with a `href="#"` which would cause the page to go to the top. That's very easy to fix but we need to see what you already have first.

Comment: Show your code (or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)).

Comment: set margin-top="whateverpx" for elements below li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others in the comments mentioned, if you have an anchor element like:

```
<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>
```

By default pressing it would cause the behavior you're experiencing, a way to prevent it to do   the following:

```
$("#remove").on("click", function(e) {
   // do your stuff here ...

   // prevent the default behavior
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. A